# What is the industry standard for automating test cases?

Tags: selenium

I am new to currently working project. They have **220** test cases to automate.

They are following the below procedure:

Assume that it has 5 features. Edit Mobile number, edit email address, edit alert, close alert, search transaction.

1. Login the app
2. Do all the above mentioned functionality
3. Logout

Maximum  functionality at one test case. But cannot derive what exactly failed but taking less time.

But what we have followed earlier:

1. Login app
2. Edit Mobile number
3. Logout

Next test case:.
1. Login app
2. Edit e-mail 
3. Logout.    Etc.  All are independent test cases but execution is time taking

Which is the industry standards? We are in the Same org but following two different approach. What is industry standard??

Comment: please revise your question, it's not clear what you are asking

Comment: One suggestion is to move all your configuration code like opening the browser and loading the URL to a '@BeforeSuite' (or '@BeforeTest') method which would be executed only ONCE for all your tests. This way, you could drastically reduce the execution time and simultaneously keep all your @Test methods independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **No** Industry standard.

Just make sure no test case should be dependent on other test cases. Note that **TestNG** dependency differs. Just for scenario :

```
@Test
public void testEditNumber(){
//should have edit number functionality
}

@Test
public void testEmailEdit(){
// should be independent of **testEdiitNumber**
}
```

You have mentioned "cannot derive what exactly failed but taking less time".

If you put all the functionality in one method , it's quite obvious that It will be hard to debug and if we will talk about time, there's  a hardly difference.

**Suggestion** :

Keep all the test method **independent**.

You can stick with what you were doing previously.

Comment: Thanks for this post.

Comment: Keeping tests independent is a good but there can be exceptions, so it's upto user.

Comment: @ShivamMishra  :   yep, but there is no industry base , right ? It's always upto the script writer , how he/she wants to drive it.

Comment: there are good and bad practices, regardless of what is standard.  Test independence is always a good practice.